# Making a Highest Rated Albums List Based on Ratings Averages from Two Models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have an `Album` model (shortened for space):

```
class Album(models.Model):
  creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
  artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  rating = models.IntegerField(
    choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 11)],
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(1)],
    default=10,
  )
  comment = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

And a `Review` model (again, shortened for space):

```
class Review(models.Model):
  reviewer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
  album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  rating = models.IntegerField(
    choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 11)],
    validators=[MaxValueValidator(10), MinValueValidator(1)],
    default=10,
  )
  comment = models.TextField()
```

The `Album` model is for users to create an Album and add their initial review and rating. The `Review` model is for users to be able to add a review to an existing album, and also a rating.

I have this model method attached to the `Album` in order to create an average rating to display in templates:

```
def avg_rating(self):
    review_ratings = 0
    orig_rating = self.rating
    review_ratings_count = self.review_set.count()

    if review_ratings_count > 0:
      for review in self.review_set.all():
        review_ratings += review.rating
        ratings_sum = review_ratings + orig_rating

      ratings_count = review_ratings_count + 1
      ratings_avg = ratings_sum / ratings_count
      avg_return = round(ratings_avg, 1)

      if avg_return == 10.0:
        avg_return = 10
      else:
        avg_return = avg_return

      return avg_return

    else:
      return self.rating
```

Sadly, `avg_rating` cannot be used (to my knowledge) in any views. So I have this view trying to create a "Highest Rated Albums" list based on accumulating the averages from both `Album.rating` and `Album.review.rating`:

```
highest_rated_albums = Album.objects.annotate(
        ratings_avg=Round(Cast((Sum('rating', distinct=True) + Sum('review__rating')), output_field=FloatField()) 
            / (Count('review__rating') + 1), precision=2)
    ).order_by('-ratings_avg')[0:10]
```

BUT whenever an album is created (without any reviews yet), it is out of order in the list, like so (it is populated to the bottom of the list):

[image]

Can anyone help?